# How to make Bootstrap 5 carousel and footer full width

Tags: html, css, carousel, footer, bootstrap-5

I'm sorry if this was already there, but it didn't help me.
I have to make a 3 pages website using Bootstrap 5 with Carousel. The problem here is that the Carousel isn't the full width as I'd like it to be.

HTML:

```html
<main class="container pt-3 mt-5 pb-3">
    <!-- Carousel -->
    <div
        id="carouselExampleControls"
        class="carousel slide border rounded"
        data-bs-ride="carousel"
        >
        <div class="carousel-inner rounded">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img
                    src="Images/Compressed/Т-34-85.jpg"
                    class="d-block w-100"
                    alt="Soviet medium tank T-34/85"
                    title="Soviet medium tank T-34/85"
                    />
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h5>T-34/85</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img
                    src="Images/Compressed/KV-1.JPG"
                    class="d-block w-100"
                    alt="Soviet heavy tank KV-1"
                    title="Soviet heavy tank KV-1"
                    />
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h5>KV-1</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img
                    src="Images/Compressed/Panzer_V_Panther.jpg"
                    class="d-block w-100"
                    alt="German medium tank Pz. V Panzer_V_Panther"
                    title="German medium tank Pz. V Panther"
                    />
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h5>Pz. V Panther</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img
                    src="Images/Compressed/Tiger_I.jpg"
                    class="d-block w-100"
                    alt="German heavy tank Pz. VI Tiger I"
                    title="German heavy tank Pz. VI Tiger I"
                    />
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h5>Pz. VI Tiger I</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img
                    src="Images/Compressed/Valentine_II.jpg"
                    class="d-block w-100"
                    alt="British infantry tank Valentine II"
                    title="British infantry tank Valentine II"
                    />
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h5>Valentine II</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img
                        src="Images/Compressed/Churchill_VI.jpg"
                        class="d-block w-100"
                        alt="British heavy tank Churchill VI"
                        title="British heavy tank Churchill VI"
                        />
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                        <h5>Churchill VI</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img
                        src="Images/Compressed/M18_Hellcat.jpg"
                        class="d-block w-100"
                        alt="American tank destroyer M18 Hellcat"
                        title="American tank destroyer M18 Hellcat"
                        />
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                        <h5>M18 Hellcat</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img
                        src="Images/Compressed/M4_Sherman.jpg"
                        class="d-block w-100"
                        alt="American medium tank M4 Sherman"
                        title="American medium tank M4 Sherman"
                        />
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                        <h5>M4 Sherman</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button
                class="carousel-control-prev rounded"
                type="button"
                data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls"
                data-bs-slide="prev"
                title="Previous"
                >
                <span
                    class="carousel-control-prev-icon"
                    aria-hidden="true"
                    ></span>
                <span class="visually-hidden">&lt;</span>
            </button>
            <button
                class="carousel-control-next rounded"
                type="button"
                data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls"
                data-bs-slide="next"
                title="Next"
            >
                <span
                    class="carousel-control-next-icon"
                    aria-hidden="true"
                ></span>
                <span class="visually-hidden">&gt;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
<!-- Footer -->
            <footer
                class="bg-primary text-white text-center text-lg-start rounded mt-2"
            >
                <div class="container p-4">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 mb-4 mb-md-0">
                            <h5 class="text-uppercase">Used references</h5>
                            <p>
                                There may be something incorrect, I'm not
                                flawless. You can check the references I used to
                                be more sure or to check information on other
                                sources.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4 mb-md-0">
                            <h5 class="text-uppercase">Information</h5>

                            <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#!" class="text-white">Link 1</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#!" class="text-white">Link 2</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#!" class="text-white">Link 3</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#!" class="text-white">Link 4</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4 mb-md-0">
                            <h5 class="text-uppercase mb-0">Pictures</h5>

                            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#!" class="text-white">Link 1</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#!" class="text-white">Link 2</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#!" class="text-white">Link 3</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#!" class="text-white">Link 4</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div
                    class="text-center p-3"
                    style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)"
                >
                    Please note, that this page is still in development. Thank
                    you for understanding.
                </div>
            </footer>
</main>
```

The CSS code is unchanged from Bootstrap.

Here is how it looks now:
[screen of the carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaNks.jpg)

Thank you in advance and have a nice day!

Comment: I think the problem is the container class.
Just try create a other class and set `width: "100vw"`
Or try with bootstrap `w-100` class

Comment: The <main> with the container class is ok, but the carousel isn't the full width of the <main>. You can see  it on the screenshot

Comment: Ah ok than try the `w-100` class on the carousell or the images

Comment: That also didn't help

Comment: are you really shure that the carousel is the problem? because on your image you have mentioned the blue stripe at the bottom is the same width as the carousel?

Comment: that's true, the footer has the same width I also need it to have the full width but it's not packed in any other container

Comment: so the footer does not take usage of the container class?

Comment: no, it doesn't those are 2 separated thing, neither of them is in another container than the <main>

Comment: yes but your `<main class="container pt-3 mt-5 pb-3">` already takes usage of the container class. or am i wrong?

Comment: That's right, as I said, there is no other container than the `<main>`

Comment: So maybe try to remove the `container` class from main or change to `container-fluid`

Comment: Ok then: https://github.com/Joedmin580/joedmin580.github.io/tree/school

Comment: Ok, so I did `style="margin-left: -0.7rem; margin-right: -0.7rem"` on the carousel and footer and now it's how I wanted it, thank you for your help. :)